# Multiple datepickers in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using `kendo UI datepicker`, I'm trying to put more than one datepicker in the same page using one function with the same ID i don't want to be changed, the first input already exists in my page but the others are added dynamically, any suggestions on how to fix that?

```js
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker">
<br>
<br>
<input id="datepicker">
<br>
<br>
<input id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Can you provide some code in order to repro your issue?

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker1">
<br>
<br>
<input id="datepicker2">
<br>
<br>
<input id="datepicker3">
```

The problem is that you are using the same id on more than one instance and this is not a good choice. The page it self is not going to give any error but when you call a tag referring it by id, it will stop on the first assuming by default the id is a unique name.

As suggested by the op on the other solution yes, you can use a class name on multiple tags and can refer all the tags by a single class

```
$(".datepicker_class").kendoDatePicker();
```

but i suggest you, in your case, as you have to deal with dates, to not create conflicts, is better to use unique id.

Simple, change id and call kendo lib as.

```
$("#datepicker1").kendoDatePicker();
$("#datepicker2").kendoDatePicker();
$("#datepicker3").kendoDatePicker();
```

Comment: Please, explain the asker that the problem was that the id should be unique and since he or she used the same id, the selector found the first match and stopped.

Comment: Right, mea culpa. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If you edit your answer and add that explanation, I will certainly upvote it. In the meantime I have written my own answer, suggesting to use class instead of id, since the asker already worked with the ids as if they were classes.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same `id` and the selector stops when the first match is found. Since you want to collect items, change the inputs to have a `mydatepicker` `class`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="mydatepicker">
<br>
<br>
<input class="mydatepicker">
<br>
<br>
<input class="mydatepicker">
```

Now, I think

```
$(".mydatepicker").kendoDatePicker();
```

should work.